# Expression in JSX Return gives "Unexpected token, expected "," "

Tags: reactjs

It's something simple I'm missing. My component takes the props `userInfo={..} small={true}`. I am getting the error

```
requestorEligibilitySection.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:14)
```

on Line 10 which is the overall content constraint

```
{props.userInfo ?
```

on the **period**, which is highlighted as the error with the expected comma.

```
export default function RequestorEligibilitySection(props) {

// Return JSX
// ----------

return (
    {props.userInfo ?
    <>
        {props.small 
         ? 
            <h3>
                {props.userInfo.organizationalstat === 'EMPLOYEE' ? 'Employee' : 'Trainee'} Eligibility
            </h3> 
         : 
            <h2>
                {props.userInfo.organizationalstat === 'EMPLOYEE' ? 'Employee' : 'Trainee'} Eligibility
            </h2>
        }
        <p>Some text</p>
    </>
    : ''
    }
);
}
```

I also tried with `{props.userInfo && .. }` around the content and it's the same error on the period. I only have 1 child, `<>..</>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra scope `{props.userInfo}` in your return expression, it expects an object definition:

```
export default function RequestorEligibilitySection(props) {
  ...
  // Not {props.userInfo ...}, remove extra {}
  return props.userInfo ? ...;
}
```

Without deleting anything, you can add a `React.Fragment` wrapper or any element so you can return a single `React.Node`:

```
export default function RequestorEligibilitySection(props) {
  ...

  // Add a wrapper
  return (
    <>
      {props.userInfo ?
        ...
      }
    </>
  );
}
```